# google sheets array and object with respect to distance between each

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array as

```
[ 'Op1-Included-Quarterly-100G',
  'Subop1-Excess-Monthly-10Hits',
  'Subop2-Included-Monthly-100Hits',
  'Op3-Flat-Monthly-1Hits',
  'subop3-Percentage-Monthly-GB',
  'Op4-Excess-Quarterly-MB',
  'op5-Flat-Monthly-KB' ]
```

I want to write the elements of array in different cells in a google sheet

I want the elements of the above array into an object with values as which cell the respective keys will be put on giving some standard distance of rows between each.

The start row is 33

1. If `Included` is found in the element add to the object with a value as `NA`
2. For an element contains `Flat`, it should add 2 rows for it
3. For every other element it should add 16 rows

This is the script I tried

```
var To_include = {};
const COLUMN_C = 'C';
const START_LINE = 33;
const len = Concat_names.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (Concat_names[i].includes("Included")){
        To_include[Concat_names[i]] = "NA";
      }
      else if((Concat_names[i].includes("Flat"))){
        var Temp_START_LINE = START_LINE + (2 * i);
        To_include[Concat_names[i]] = Temp_START_LINE;
      }
      else {
        var Temp_START_LINE = START_LINE + (16 * i);
          To_include[Concat_names[i]] = COLUMN_C + Temp_START_LINE;
      }
    }
```

The o/p I get is

```
To Include: { 'Op1-Included-Quarterly-100G': 'NA',
  'Subop2-Included-Monthly-100Hits': 'NA',
  'Subop1-Excess-Monthly-10Hits': 'C49',
  'Op3-Flat-Monthly-1Hits': 'C39',
  'subop3-Percentage-Monthly-GB': 'C97',
  'Op4-Excess-Quarterly-MB' : 'C43',
  'op5-Flat-Monthly-KB': 'C129' }
```

I want the o/p to be as

```
To Include: { 'Op1-Included-Quarterly-100G': 'NA',
  'Subop2-Included-Monthly-100Hits': 'NA',
  'Subop1-Excess-Monthly-10Hits': 'C33',
  'Op3-Flat-Monthly-1Hits': 'C49',
  'subop3-Percentage-Monthly-GB': 'C51',
  'Op4-Excess-Quarterly-MB' : 'C67',
  'op5-Flat-Monthly-KB': 'C83'}
```

Please guide

Comment: `Concat_names` is the top array? If my understanding is correct, I think that `const len = Concat_names.length();` occurs an error. How about this? And, in your expected result, `subop3-Overage-Monthly-10000 HTTP Hits` is included. But, in your input value, that is not included. And, in your input value, `subop3-Percentage-Monthly-GB` is included. But, in your expected result, that is not included. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the logic for achieving your expected result from your input value. I apologize for this. Can you provide the detailed logic for achieving your expected result?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike san. I updated the code with some corrections.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that, I want to put the keys of the object in the respective cell range as their values are.

I have a fixed start row as ```START_LINE```which is 33 now from here I will add as the order goes, like in this example ```Subop1-Excess-Monthly-10Hits``` should come on ```C33``` now we got to add 16 from there and and then the next item after it is ```Op3-Flat-Monthly-1Hits``` should be added at ```C49``` , Now as this contains ```Flat``` I will add two rows only to it and next item ```subop3-Percentage-Monthly-GB``` should come at ```C51``` and so on

Comment: This link sheet may give some idea - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQUG4TmFTKghV8r6Gg3EilLx6zyuTkrNfnCatRVWp_U/edit#gid=688991972

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your current expected value, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion.

  - From

    ```
      [ 'Op1-Included-Quarterly-100G',
        'Subop1-Excess-Monthly-10Hits',
        'Subop2-Included-Monthly-100Hits',
        'Op3-Flat-Monthly-1Hits',
        'subop3-Percentage-Monthly-GB',
        'Op4-Excess-Quarterly-MB',
        'op5-Flat-Monthly-KB' ]
    ```
  - To

    ```
      { 'Op1-Included-Quarterly-100G': 'NA',
        'Subop2-Included-Monthly-100Hits': 'NA',
        'Subop1-Excess-Monthly-10Hits': 'C33',
        'Op3-Flat-Monthly-1Hits': 'C49',
        'subop3-Percentage-Monthly-GB': 'C51',
        'Op4-Excess-Quarterly-MB' : 'C67',
        'op5-Flat-Monthly-KB': 'C83'}
    ```

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var Concat_names = [
  'Op1-Included-Quarterly-100G',
  'Subop1-Excess-Monthly-10Hits',
  'Subop2-Included-Monthly-100Hits',
  'Op3-Flat-Monthly-1Hits',
  'subop3-Percentage-Monthly-GB',
  'Op4-Excess-Quarterly-MB',
  'op5-Flat-Monthly-KB'
];
var To_include = {};
const COLUMN_C = 'C';
const START_LINE = 33;
const len = Concat_names.length;
let offset = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (Concat_names[i].includes("Included")) {
    To_include[Concat_names[i]] = "NA";
  } else if (Concat_names[i].includes("Flat")) {
    var Temp_START_LINE = START_LINE + offset;
    To_include[Concat_names[i]] = COLUMN_C + Temp_START_LINE;
    offset += 2;
  } else {
    var Temp_START_LINE = START_LINE + offset;
    To_include[Concat_names[i]] = COLUMN_C + Temp_START_LINE;
    offset += 16;
  }
}
console.log(To_include);
```

- When this script is run, your expected value is obtained.

Comment: It works like a charm, you are super genius @Tanaike - san